# GWT compile POJO

Tags: gwt, compiler-construction, gwt-compiler

I'm trying to use just the Java to Javascript compiler of the GWT from Ant.

Can I use the GWT compiler without extending any Google classes such as `com.google.gwt.core.Core` or similar. If so how? I'm currently using the setup below on GWT 2.4.0.

I'm calling the ant task:

**build.xml**

```
 <target name="gwtc" description="GWT compile to JavaScript (production mode)">
    <java failonerror="true" fork="true" classname="com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler">
      <classpath>
        <pathelement location="src"/>
        <path refid="project.class.path"/>
        <pathelement location="${gwt.sdk}/validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar" />
        <pathelement location="${gwt.sdk}/validation-api-1.0.0.GA-sources.jar" />
      </classpath>
      <!-- add jvmarg -Xss16M or similar if you see a StackOverflowError -->
      <jvmarg value="-Xmx256M"/>
      <arg line="-war"/>
      <arg value="war"/>
      <!-- Additional arguments like -style PRETTY or -logLevel DEBUG -->
      <arg line="${gwt.args}"/>
      <arg value="foo.Test1"/>
    </java>
  </target>
```

**foo/Test.java**

```
package foo;

public class Test1 {
    public String field1;
    public String field2;
    public int field3;

}
```

**foot/Test1.gwt.xml**

```
<module rename-to="hello">
    <source path="foo.Test1"/>
    <!--entry-point class="foo.Test1"/-->
</module>
```

And output:

```
gwtc:
     [java] Compiling module foo.Test1
     [java]    [ERROR] Unable to find type 'java.lang.Object'
     [java]       [ERROR] Hint: Check that your module inherits 'com.google.gwt.core.Core' either directly or indirectly (most often by inheriting module 'com.google.gwt.user.User')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates that you need to inherit `'com.google.gwt.core.Core'` in your `gwt.xml` file and it is not saying that your class should extend/implement it. Give this a try:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE 
    module 
    PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 2.3.0//EN" 
    "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/tags/2.3.0/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">

<module rename-to="hello">
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.core.Core" />
    <source path="foo" />
</module>
```

Or is it that you don't want your module to inherit it?

Comment: I had to include an entry-point point but this put me on the right track, thanks.

Comment: Do you know I can make public methods from the Test1 class available in the generated Javascript?

Comment: As far as I know the GWT compiler detects unused code/methods and prunes them in the generated JavaScript code. I am not sure how one can disable pruning. By the way, if you only want a toolkit for converting Java classes to JavaScript, have a look at DWR (Direct Web Remoting).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try and find how to disable this.   We already use DWR but it doesn't convert Java to Javascript instead it makes remote Java objects accessible from Javascript via a Javascript stub and behind the scenes AJAX call.